# Recursively list file paths to excel column separating with delimiter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export all .jpg file paths of a directory recursively with a separating delimiter (chose pipe character) such that each sub folder's file contents (.jpg file paths) are listed as new cell in a column. So imagine we are in directory:

```
X:\My\Files
```

This folder contains the following folders and files

```
Folder1\img1.jpg
Folder1\img2.jpg
Folder2\img3.jpg
Folder2\img4.jpg
```

What I want the output to be

```
X:\My\Files\Folder1\img1.jpg|X:\my\Files\Folder1\img2.jpg ## 1st cell of csv column
X:\My\Files\Folder2\img3.jpg|X:\my\Files\Folder2\img4.jpg ## 2nd cell of csv column
```

My command so far

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path X:\My\Files -Include *.jpg -Recurse) -join "|" | Add-Content -path C:\Users\Anon\Documents\file.csv | Select-Object FullName
```

This is able to get me all file paths separated with pipe delimiter, but only into one cell which is useless. I need it to respect directory structure like listed above in my desired output.

Any advice?

Comment: I seem to recall that CSV files will create columns based on commas, so add a comma where you want to create the columns.

Comment: @user4317867 Thanks for the reply. I tried adding "," before/after join and inside the (), no variation seemed to worked. Changing my join delimiter to a comma, putt each file path in a new cell within a row, not a column. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to group items by a certain criteria you would have to use `Group-Object` in this case the criteria is the `DirectoryName`.

Once they are grouped we can then join them using any delimiter and export the results to a csv.

In the below command, we create a hash-table and then extract just the values out of the hashtable

```
$hash = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.jpg -Recurse | 
  Group-Object directoryname -AsHashTable -AsString

$hash.GetEnumerator() | 
  ForEach-Object { [PSCustomobject]@{Path = $_.value.fullname -join '|'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\paths.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't quite get your command working, maybe it's because I'm using an older version of PS. I used a very similar work around though, but not with hash-table. Thanks again.